# Computing values in an array that "surround" a distinct value outside the array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Say we have a sorted integer array A with n distinct values, and we are given some value M which is not contained in A.

For example: A = [2,3,5,8,10], and M = 4.
The problem requires us to find the x "surrounding values" in relation to M where x will be an even number from 1 to n.
If x is 2, we will return [3,5]. If x is 4, return [2,3,5,8].
This process makes sense to me, how we are essentially finding M's place in the sorted array and taking the values on either side as we increment x, and it's clear to see how this can be done in linear time.  However, what if the initial array was not in fact sorted and still followed the same requirements with input and output.

For example, if A was A = [8,5,10,2,3], and M = 4, setting x to 2 should still return [3,5].  There is a linear time algorithm that exists to solve it, but if someone could give some pointers or direction that would be extremely helpful.  I considered counting sort, but we do not know the maximum size of the integers so I feel it would not be wise to use it in this situation.

Comment: Is M constant? If not - is O(NlogM) suitable?

Comment: @MBo Only O(n) where n is the number of elements in A

Comment: Should we consider logM as constant too?

Comment: @MBo O(n + x) is acceptable

Comment: Just to clarify - n is elements in array. M is some number not in A. x is the neighborhood size.

Comment: I suspect that approach with priority queue with key=difference with given value is the best possible. But queue size is X and delete-max operation takes log(X), so overall time is O(N*(log(X))

Comment: Seems like [this is what you're looking for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Unordered_partial_sorting).

Comment: @MBo I think I have an O(n) solution. What do you think?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן  Excellent catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible in `O(n)` time. Create two lists: one with all the elements in the array that are greater than `M` and the other with all the elements in the array that are smaller than `M`. Now use a [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the `x/2`th element smallest element in the `larger_than_list` and the `(|smaller_than_list| - x/2)`th element in the `smaller_than_list`. [Prune](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pruning) the lists.

Comment: That would work if the output does not have to be sorted. And it seems that indeed the OP does not require this.

Comment: Cool idea! Haven't thought of that.